# on index match runing function stop jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, indexing

If index match then function should not work, And if different index match then show that index's Element and continue and here is my code:

HTML

```
 <ul>
    <li id="foo">foo</li>
    <li id="bar">bar</li>
    <li id="baz">baz</li>

</ul>
    <div class="a">e</div>
    <div class="a">f</div>
    <div class="a">g</div>
```

CSS

```
    .a{display:none;}
```

jQuery

```
    var t,flag;

    $('li').click(function(){  
      t=$(this).index();
      if ($("div.c").eq(t).is(":visible") == true) { 
                flag=0;      //should continue without loading page
             }                        
      else { 
                $('.a').fadeOut();
                $('div.a').eq(t).fadeIn(); 
           }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a couple of syntax errors:

Line 5: `$("div.c"):eq(t).is(":visible")` => `$("div.c").eq(t).is(":visible")`

Line 12: `}` => `});`

```
var t, flag;

$('li').click(function () {
    t = $(this).index();
    if ($("div.c").eq(t).is(":visible")) {
        flag = 0; //should continue without loading page
    } else {
        $('.a').fadeOut();
        $('div.a').eq(t).fadeIn();
    }
});
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/_wilmer/nzA6X/) : I used only div.a for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

change `if ($("div.c"):eq(t).is(":visible") == true) {`
to 
`if ($("div.c").eq(t).is(":visible") == true) {`

http://jsfiddle.net/FV5Bc/